# macOS check is Bluetooth is supported programmatically

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I need to determine if the bluetooth is supported on macOS in Objective-C or Swift ?

Thanks

Comment: What macOS hardware doesn't support Bluetooth? Are you thinking about environments where Bluetooth is disabled by policy? What situation do you have in mind here?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, I think yes (a hardware problem, ...), I need to test it.

Comment: You need to test what? If there's a hardware problem, there definitely isn't a simple API call that will tell you the hardware is broken. (In that case, Bluetooth is "supported," so to your question, the correct response would be true, even though it doesn't work.) Do you have broken hardware that you're trying to help users diagnose? That's likely a very complex project.

Comment: It's possible or not to detect is the the bluetooth adapter is active or inactive like Linux ?

Comment: What specific programmatic thing "like LInux" do you mean? What C code would you write on Linux that would do what you mean? (Bluetooth is a broad topic that includes several somewhat unrelated protocols. BLE is not the same as BT Audio is not the same as a BT network adapter. Perhaps `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you want to know if Bluetooth is switched on in the system prefs?

Comment: @Rob Napier
 what does `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` return if no bluetooth card is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth is always supported. But I believe the thing you're looking for is  the IOBluetoothHostController:

```
import IOBluetooth

let controller = IOBluetoothHostController.default()!
print(controller.powerState)
```

While `.default()` returns an implicitly unwrapped optional (because it lacks optionality annotations), I don't believe it's possible for it to actually return nil. There is always a Bluetooth module.

You probably want to read [Bluetooth on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH215-TPXREF16), though I don't believe it's fully up-to-date (it references some non-existent classes, though it's possible some of those classes are merely private).